# Animals stuck on my head

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I was playing Minecraft with the Mo' Creatures mod and got and cat and a bunny stuck on my head. I had to kill the cat because it wouldn't come off, but I don't want to kill the bunny this time. I tried right-clicking with a pickaxe and without, but nothing I've tried worked.

Comment: Should right-clicking (always) work in that case?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the key binds?

Answer (score 0):

The only other way to get mobs off your head that I could find is to restart your server / game. Looking up and right clicking with a picaxe or an open hand should work but if it's not than reloging is probably the only way to fix it.